# Can we use parse to create two different kind of users with two different functionality.

Tags: android, parse-platform

We have developed an android app where the user can select few apparels and request for delivery (Cash on Delivery). Till now we were syncing the apparels from our web app. Now we want to transform the android app to an independent entity. Can we use parse to create two different kind of users

1. where the user can only browse product and order
2. where the merchant can upload products and their details.

Can we get the approach for doing this. We are using Android Studio for development.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, and you can do that.

There are some ways to get that. On parse, when you create the user entity (by default), you will get "role" entity, that allow you create roles for your users.

Another way, (I'm currently using this for one project), is set to user entity a property like isAdmin or something like that as a boolean and then, you will check that to show the correct layout.

I hope this help you.